# Saving order update on server

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

the interface of an app allows the items to be ordered by drag and drop. When an item is rearranged, the `order` property of all the items will be updated to match its new order. I use [Sortable.js](http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/) for this functionality, so far everything is fine.

Now I want to save these new ordered elements to the server. For example in my route I fetch all favorites:

```
model: ->
  return this.store.find('favorite')
```

After reordering some of my favorites, I do  `this.get('model').save()`.  This way all my favorite records are seperately saved to the server with a PUT request per favorite `PUT > /api/favorites/2`.

This works fine when I don't have too many favorites, but this approach feels wrong when e.g I have 50 favorites and on every reorder I will send 50 PUT requests.

What would be a better approach for persisting the order of different records to the server?

Comment: Ember-data doesn't support batch operations, it did at one time, but was removed, I believe they plan to add it again in the near future. https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md#transaction-is-gone-save-individual-records,

Comment: if there is a parent model you can save the parent and embed all the children to do it in one call using Ember's [EmbeddeRecordsMixin](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html).  this works well with rail's accepts_nested_attributes_for